# How to use kivymd.ResponsiveLayout?

Tags: python, kivymd

I'm learning `kivymd`, and I want to use the `ResponsiveLayout` defined at a `.kv` file.

`.py` code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("startpage.kv")

Test().run()
```

`.kv` file:

```
<MobileView>:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Mobile"
        halign: "center"


<TabletView>:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Tablet"
        halign: "center"


<DesktopView>:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Desktop"
        halign: "center"


ResponsiveLayout:
    
    mobile_view:
        MobileView
    tablet_view:
        TabletView
    desktop_view:
        DesktopView
```

I get this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\acgc9\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-04-20_32.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.0.dev0, git-0fc8c67, 20230419
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-04-20 (installed at "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 25.20.100.6617'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 25.20.100.6617'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\Desktop\test\main.py", line 8, in <module>
     Test().run()
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\Desktop\test\main.py", line 6, in build
     return Builder.load_file("startpage.kv")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 403, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 147, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <ResponsiveLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use kivymd docks in this link https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/components/responsivelayout/index.html

In this link kivymd docks explain how to use MDResponsiveLayout and how it works.

This is kivymd example code to make ResponsiveView:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.responsivelayout import MDResponsiveLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

KV = '''
<CommonComponentLabel>
    halign: "center"


<MobileView>
    CommonComponentLabel:
        text: "Mobile"


<TabletView>
    CommonComponentLabel:
        text: "Table"


<DesktopView>
    CommonComponentLabel:
        text: "Desktop"


ResponsiveView:
'''


class CommonComponentLabel(MDLabel):
    pass


class MobileView(MDScreen):
    pass


class TabletView(MDScreen):
    pass


class DesktopView(MDScreen):
    pass


class ResponsiveView(MDResponsiveLayout, MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.mobile_view = MobileView()
        self.tablet_view = TabletView()
        self.desktop_view = DesktopView()


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```